# Assign a unique ID to each name in a table where names are repeated

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains millions of sales records and looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
`dollar_amount` INT NULL,
`transaction_date` DATE NULL,
`company_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`company_id` INT NULL);
```

The first three columns are populated with data. I would like to insert data into the company_id column that will identify each company with an auto_incremented integer. I plan to use the company_id field as a foreign key referencing another table that will contain each company's details. Many companies have multiple transactions, so the code needs to assign the same company_id to each row in the sales table with a matching company_name.

Is there a way to do this using only MySQL?

Comment: Why not use company_name as the primary key in this case? Otherwise look at stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd recommend creating the `company` table:

```
CREATE TABLE company (
    company_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    company_name VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY(company_id));
```

Then insert the companies from your sales data:

```
INSERT INTO company (company_name)
SELECT distinct company_name
FROM sales;
```

Finally, update your `sales` table with a `join` to get the `company_id`:

```
UPDATE sales s
  JOIN company c ON s.company_name = c.company_name
SET s.company_id = c.company_id;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b6eed/1)

You should also remove the `company_name` field from the `sales` table since this is now stored in the `company` table.

Answer (score 0):

To define an auto incremented integer, you just use the `AUTO_INCREMENT` keyword. However, if you define any columns as auto_increment, you must also make that column your primary key. Which, in this case, would make sense in order for it to be a foreign key elsewhere.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
`dollar_amount` INT NULL,
`transaction_date` DATE NULL,
`company_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`company_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(company_id);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ea8cf)

Comment: I am trying to uniquely identify each company, not each transaction. For example, when I insert two transactions by the same company, I want both of those records to get the same company_id. With your table, transactions by the same company are getting different company_ids. Maybe auto_increment isn't suitable for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you could add another field, like sales_id? You might benefit from having one table for the company, and one table for the sales, and have the sales table reference the company id